# Sum of divisors of an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

For $n$ a positive integer, we define $s(n)$ the sum of the divisors $d$ of $n$ such that $d \neq 1$ and $d \neq n$. For example $s(6)=2+3=5$, and $s(5)=0$, because $5$ is a prime number.

Is it possible $s(n)=n$ ?

For $n=48$, we have $s(48)=2+3+4+6+8+12+16+24=75$ and $s(75)=3+5+15+25=48$. So, for $n=48$, $s^2(n)=n$.

For $k>2$ a positive integer, and $n>0$ a positive integer, is it possible $s^k(n)=n$, with $s^2(n)\neq n$ ?

Comment: Using the usual $\sigma(n)$ defined as the sum including $1,n$ this is equivalent to solving $\sigma(n)=2n+1.$

Comment: In that case, they are [Quasiperfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiperfect_number), and none has been found, although some lower bounds are established.

Comment: just a question, is $s(4)=2+2+4=8$ or $s(4)=2+4=6$?

Comment: For the second question, we turn to [Quasiamicable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betrothed_numbers), and Wikipedia is kind enough to include the first quasi-sociable sequence found.

Comment: @CSquared $s(4)=2.$

Comment: @player3236: thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some observations I made. I will come back tomorrow to look more into this.

Observe that $s(n)=\sigma(n)-n-1$ (read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) about $\sigma(n)$, the divisor sum function).

$n=\sigma(n)-n-1\Leftrightarrow\sigma(n)=2n+1$.

Let $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_k^{a_k}$. Then, the above equation is equivalent to

$$\sigma(n)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}\frac{p_i^{a_i+1}-1}{p_i-1}=\prod_{i=1}^{k}\big(1+p_i+p_i^2+...+p_i^{a_i}\big)=2\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i^{a_i}+1=2n+1$$

So we get that $n=2^ab^2$

So $\sigma(2^ab^2)=\sigma(2^a)\cdot\sigma(b^2)=(2^{a+1}-1)\sigma(b^2)=2^{a+1}b^2+1=(2^{a+1}-1)b^2+b^2+1$

So $2^{a+1}-1|b^2+1$. If $a\geq 1$, $2^{a+1}-1\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ so the exists a prime $p$ such that $p|2^{a+1}-1$, so $p|b^2+1$, so by this lemma:

> For any prime $p$ such that $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, if $p|a^2+b^2$, then $p|a$ and $p|b$.

we get $p|1$, contradiction. So $a=0$

So $n=b^2$ with odd $b$.